# Character limit doesn't include @replies that will be deleted

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, comment-replies, character-limit

When you type in a comment, there is a little meter showing how much more text you need to write for the comment to be long enough. When you have an @reply to the OP of an answer or question, the @reply is automatically deleted when you comment. However, in the shown number of characters in the comment is still counted:

[image]

This leads to a rather comfusing situation. Had I not already heard about that rule, I would have had no idea what was going on.

I think there should be something to tell the user why their comment isn't long enough in this case.